# Recovering English Words In Noisy Data

Tags: probability

I'm trying to design an algorithm for recovering English text from noisy data (teletext on VHS). To that end I have a dictionary of English words (7 bit ASCII) and their frequencies, which I can match to the input.

I want to improve on my current method, which is simply to search every single word and count bit differences between the word and the input. The one with the lowest number of differences wins. If more than one word satisfies this, then I choose the word with the highest frequency.

I can fairly reliably detect word boundaries (spaces) so I only have to search the dictionary for fixed length words and compare bits.

My question is that it may be possible to have a greater number of bits that differ, but because the word is much more frequent, I should chose that instead.

So in order to choose the most likely word, I would need an expression that takes the bit error rate, the particular word frequency, the length of the word in bits, and the number of bit matches, to produce a value I can use to sort my list of probabilities.

I have 'A' Level maths, but my brain can't do it. Help!?

Comment: You will have a better chance here: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might consider a Bayesian framework. Perhaps word frequencies can be expressed as _prior probabilities_ and percentages of matching bits as _likelihoods._ Then _posterior probabilities_ are proportional to products of priors and likelihoods. Max posterior wins. Perhaps stratify on (approximate?) word length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some empirical testing and a bit of guesswork, I have the answer. If someone can elaborate on how to derive from first principles, I'd be grateful.

So, the probability of having $m$ bits in error, in an $n$ bit word length, with an error rate $r$ (i.e. 1 bit in every $r$ bits in error on average), is:

$$p =  {n\choose m}\frac{(r-1)^{n-m}}{r^n}$$

I can then use this probability and multiply by the frequency of the English word, to obtain a value for ranking the likelihood of the word.